# doctrine/annotations updated from 1.2.7 to 1.3.0 is slowing my application

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've updated composer packages in my Symfony 3.0.* project. Before the update, my app was loading in about ~700ms. Now is loading in **~3000ms**. In updated packages there was an update of `doctrine/annotations` from `v1.2.7` to `v1.3.0`. When I reverted all changes from this package, everything back to normal state with the speed.

Which of the changes in `doctrine/annotations` are destroying my speed? How to fix it?

Configuration:

## [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed exactly same issue few days ago - have checked on both Symfony 3.1.5 & 3.1.6. 
I have also checked dev-master version of doctrine-annotations but it does not help either.

It seems issue is only related to DEV environment as PROD seems to have more or less comparable times than before.

My environment is PHP7 (if it does matter)

Comparison of average times for same page & code (cache warmed up):

- doctrine annotations 1.2.* => ~300ms
- doctrine annotations 1.3.0/dev-master => ~4000ms

At this moment my only solution was to add "doctrine/annotations":"1.2.*" into composer.json.

**[UPDATE 12.01.2017]**
Symfony 3.2.1 with doctrine/annotations 1.3.1 seems to work better (comparable times to 1.2.x in my use cases)

Comment: Damn... maybe it's global issue, not only mine. Thanks for the info.

Comment: for those who are still interested: doctrine/annotations 1.3.1 with symfony 3.2.1 seems to be free of that issue - times are more or less normal on DEV environment

Comment: Thanks for the info! ;)